# How to reduce a set of lines to take the average?

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

I have a file with lines like these (columns are tab seperated)

```
2    1.414455    3.70898
2    2.414455    3.80898
2    3.414455    3.90898
2    1.414455    3.90898
4    4.414455    7.23898
4    3.414455    6.23898
4    5.414455    8.23898
```

i.e. there are consecutive lines where the first column is an integer, and rest two columns are floats.

I want to reduce them as below

```
2    2.164455    3.75898
4    4.414455    7.23898
```

**where I keep the first columns, and take the averages of the second and third columns for all elements with same first columns**. The number of consecutive lines with same first elements might be different, but they will always be consecutive.

I can do this in perl, but was wondering if there is a simpler bash / sed / awk mix that can do the same for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2;b[$1]+=$3;c[$1]++;}END{for(i in c)print i, a[i]/c[i],b[i]/c[i];}' file
2 2.16445 3.83398
4 4.41446 7.23898
```

Using 3 different arrays: a and b to keep the sum of 2nd and 3rd columns, c to keep the count of elements. At the end, calculating the average and printing it.

Comment: Works nicely! But the values are printed in reverse order, line with 4 is printed first, and then the line with 2.

Comment: @Moeb : if you want the output in sorted order, you can pipe this awk command with "sort -n" which will give the result sorted.

Comment: Guru, that was a nice code.. My approach was way too long :-)